Getting error "Reason: Unable to determine color type. Type mismatch: Cannot replace Call with str"
I have an assignment for creating cost for a sign. I have done everything for the assignment, and the code even runs perfectly the way it wants it. however, it keeps giving me the error "Reason: Unable to determine color type. Type mismatch: Cannot replace Call with str".
This is my code. It works fine. For example, it wants the price of a gold text sign, with 8 letters and pine to be 62$ which is what the price ends up being by the end of the program.
# Initialize variables here.
charge = 0
num_chars = 8
color = "gold"
wood_type = "oak"
minChars = 5
costChars = 4

# Charge for this sign.

# Number of characters.
print("The first five letters are included in the minimum charge, but each individual character afterwards is an additional 4$")
num_chars = int(input("Enter how many characters you will have on the sign: "))
if num_chars > minChars:
    charge = (num_chars - minChars) * costChars
# Color of characters.
color = input("Do you wan to pay 15$ additional for gold lettering or black and white: ")
if color == "gold":
    charge = charge + 15
elif color == "black and white":
    charge
# Type of wood.
wood_type = input("Do you wan to pay 20$ additional oak or pine: ")
if wood_type == "oak":
    charge = charge + 20
elif wood_type == "pine":
    charge
# Write assignment and if statements here as appropriate.

# Output Charge for this sign.
charge = charge + 35
print(f"The charge for this sign is ${charge:.2f}")`

This is the output containing the errors:
Status: FAILED!
Check: 1
Test: Black and white, 5 letter, on pine (minimum charge).
Reason: Unable to determine color type. Type mismatch: Cannot replace Call with str.
Error : ValueError - Unable to determine color type. Type mismatch: Cannot replace Call with str.
Timestamp: 2024-04-27 20:20:03.443145

Status: FAILED!
Check: 2
Test: Gold leaf, 10 letter, on oak.
Reason: Unable to determine color type. Type mismatch: Cannot replace Call with str.
Error : ValueError - Unable to determine color type. Type mismatch: Cannot replace Call with str.
Timestamp: 2024-04-27 20:20:03.443463

Status: FAILED!
Check: 3
Test: Gold leaf, 8 letter, on pine.
Reason: Unable to determine color type. Type mismatch: Cannot replace Call with str.
Error : ValueError - Unable to determine color type. Type mismatch: Cannot replace Call with str.
Timestamp: 2024-04-27 20:20:03.443735

This is the assignment: Assignment
This is the code given: original code

I guess the error is given by the school's software which evaluates his code.

Note: elif color == "black and white": charge and elif wood_type == "pine": charge do nothing and can be removed.

"Type mismatch: Cannot replace Call with str" refers to your output. I think it's expecting a return type of Call Maybe this is a class that was given to you? I see you are printing out strings, that could be your issue

Maybe your code shouldn't output anything else besides the last print that was provided?

@mkrieger1 that's what I thought, but when I looked at the errors, it required a different set of conditions. Some wanted 5 characters, others wanted 10, so it implies that it wants input

I'm in COP 1000 and had the same errors. I got rid of the user inputs and ran it. It didn't have any error codes after I removed the inputs.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
